# Amazon category sub categories urls extraction till last category using python

Tags: python, infinite-scroll, data-extraction

[Sample categories image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go0RQ.jpg) I am new in Python,i develop following code in Python for categories url extraction,my code is working fine but actully i want to extract infinte urls i.e category url then all sub categories url and extract till no category found i.e upto last category.For example main cateogry is books,in first now i able to extact all sub cateogry url of books and now my requirement is to browse all extracted links till no sub category remains ie. upto last sub category of books.Sample categories and sub categories image attached please.My first category code is given below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url ="https://www.amazon.com/s?i=stripbooks&bbn=283155&rh=n%3A283155%2Cp_n_feature_browse-bin%3A2656022011&dc&qid=1636126733&ref=sr_ex_n_1"

HEADERS ={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate", "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "DNT":"1","Connection":"close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
print(r)
file = open(r"parseddata.csv", "w")

counts=soup.find('div', {'class' :'a-section a-spacing-small a-spacing-top-small'}).text
cat=soup.find('div', {'class' :'nav-search-facade'}).text
links = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'a-link-normal s-navigation-item'})
#print(counts)
#print(cat)
for link in links:
file.write(cat + counts + link.get('href')+ '\n')
file.close()
```

Comment: send cookie in header

Comment: in following header headers = {'Us,please share cookies syntax